# Fire push notification after delay using CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit

I am working on push notifications using CloudKit. Generally, I use the option `.firesOnRecordCreation` to identify when I want the push notification to send. E.g. -

```
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "SomeRecord", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil), options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(subscription) { (result, error) -> Void in
    //check for result and error
}
```

This is a `CKQuerySubscriptionOptions`. However, I want to send the push notifications a few days later. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to set a delay for the delivery of CloudKit push notifications. CloudKit delivers notifications at some point after a change occurs that satisfies a subscription. There is no app developer control of the timing of this process, and the timing may be impacted by multiple variables.

If you want to display a notification to the user at a later date, you could work around this by scheduling a Local Notification for that date (after you've received the CloudKit notification).

Alternatively, you could record the changed record / notification information in your app, and handle it as appropriate when the app is running.

Or, if you're willing to run your own server and/or send your own push notifications, the sky is the limit.